# Java - New Line Character Issue

Tags: java

I have a code like,

```
String str = " " ; 

while(  cond ) {

  str = str + "\n" ;

}
```

Now, I don't know why at the time of printing, the output string is not printing the newline character. However, when I add any other character like ( str = str + "c"), it is printing properly. Can anybody help me, how to solve this problem and why this happening ?

Comment: What are you using to print out the `str`?

Comment: What do you mean by "not printing"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to run the above code on Windows. Well the line separator or new line is different on Windows ( '\r\n' ) and Unix flavors ('\n').

So, instead of hard coding and using '\n' as new line. Try getting new line from the system like:

```
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String str = " " ; 

while(  cond ) {

  str = str + newLine ;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The newline character is considered a [control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character), which doesn't print a special character to the screen by default.

As an example, try this:

```
String str = "Hi";
while (cond) {
    str += "\n"; // Syntactically equivalent to your code
}
str += "Bye";
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want \n, to get printed, do it like this.

```
String first = "C:/Mine/Java" + "\\n";
System.out.println(first);
```

OUTPUT is as follows :

[image: NEWLINE]

For a good reference as to why is this happening, visit [JAVA Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

**As referred in that TUTORIAL :**  A character preceded by a backslash is an escape sequence, and has a special meaning to the compiler. When an escape sequence is encountered in a print statement, the compiler interprets it accordingly

Hope this might help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample, the only reason it would not show a new line character is that `cond` is never true and thus the while loop never runs...